Loop through relationships and insert into all when user is created
I have a Users model/table in Laravel 11.x with a lot of One to One relationships (e.g. profile, resources, etc.)
Primary key in all of those related tables is user_id.
I want to loop through all these relationships and create a row in each when a user is created (with default column values).
I had this:
$user = User::create([...]);
$user->profile()->create();
$user->resources()->create();
...

but i keep adding these tables and I want a row for that user to be inserted for all one-to-one relationships as well (as soon as user is created) without having to add every new table in 2 places and by just relying on relationships.
I have tried:
$relations = $user->relationsToArray();

foreach ($relations as $relationName => $relationInfo) {
   if($relationInfo['type'] === 'hasOne') {
       $user->{$relationName}()->create();
   }
}

but $user->relationsToArray() returns an empty array.

Which version of laravel you are using?

@Subha Laravel 11.x

When i checked the API docs it says that relationsToArray will return the relations attributes as array not defined relationship in the model
https://laravel.com/api/11.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_relationsToArray

If you want to get all the defined relations you need to use ReflectionClass and then filter out the method based on return type only for relation and then form a array with keys as per your need.

@ManojKiran Thank you! I tried ReflectionClass and it works. is it reliable and okay performance wise? I'm surprised others don't do this more often like do you just insert into these other tables on first fetch if it doesn't exist?

Please make sure to use proper return type for the relationship methods. And For performance its better to cache the method names until the file is modified.

This sounds like incredibly bad practice. A relationship only actually exist IF there is a subordinate record in existence.

what is the point of creating these empty relations?

Are you having the same data to be inserted to profiles and resources? If so, what about combining those tables together, or removing one of them?
To avoid repeating code, you might implement model events:
class User extends Authenticable
{
    protected static function booted(): void
    {
        static::created(function (User $user) {
            $user->profile()->create(request(...));
            $user->resources()->create(request(...));
        });
    }
}


Well each user has a profile by default, for example gender set to unknown and name and stuff null. I just want to create those rows by default when user is created instead of checking every time if user has those records and if not create them. and no, different data in each table, I just don't want to have a very large users table with everything in it. your answer is exactly what I was looking for thank you!! BUT any idea how to make that run in DB transaction? just to make sure either everything is created or none of them.

I mean I just don't want a user to be created without the relationships. so either user AND all relationships are created, or neither.
